# given an array A of N integers, returns the smallest positive integer (greater than 0) that does not occur in A

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I tried to solve this exercise
I got 66 percent
I can not understand why
can you help?

---

The exercise is:
Write a function:

int solution(vector &A);

that, given an array A of N integers, returns the smallest positive integer (greater than 0) that does not occur in A.

For example, given A = [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2], the function should return 5.

Given A = [1, 2, 3], the function should return 4.

Given A = [−1, −3], the function should return 1.
The solution I wrote is:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

int solution(vector<int> &A) {
    if (A.size() == 0 || (A.size() == 1 && A.at(0) <= 0))
        return 1;
    if (A.size() == 1)
        return A.at(0) + 1;

    sort(A.begin(), A.end());
    if (A.at(A.size() - 1) <= 0)
        return 1;

    auto ip = std::unique(A.begin(), A.end());
    A.resize(distance(A.begin(), ip));
    A.erase(remove_if(A.begin(), A.end(), [](const int i) { return i < 0; }),A.end());
    if (A.at(0) != 1)
        return 1;
    if (A.size() == 1)
        return (A.at(0) != 1 ? 1 : 2);
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < A.size(); ++i) {
        if (A.at(i) != i + 1)
            return A.at(i - 1) + 1;
    }
    return A.at(A.size()) + 1;
}
```

Comment: The logic is roughly here, you have to debug to fix issue. Write unit-test and/or try to find input which produce wrong output.

Comment: FYI `std::sort` and `adjacent_find` makes this a [trivial and much shorter solution](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12835c8784a8aa42), without having to resize, erase, remove, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The following algorithm has a complexity O(n). No need to sort or to erase.

We know that the first missing value is less or equal to `n+1`, if `n` is the array size.

Then we simply have to use an array of size n+2, `present[n+2]`, initialised to 0, and then to look at all values `A[i]`:

```
if (A[i] <= 1+n && A[i] > 0) present[A[i]] = 1;
```

Finally, in a second step we simply have to examine the array `present[.]`, and search for the first index `k` such that `present[k]==0.`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int find_missing (const std::vector<int> &A) {
    int n = A.size();
    std::vector<int> present (n+2, 0);
    int vmax = n+1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (A[i] <= vmax && A[i] > 0) {
            present[A[i]] = 1;
        }
    }
    for (int k = 1; k <= vmax; ++k) {
        if (present[k] == 0) return k;
    }
    return -1;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> A = {1, 2, 0, 3, -3, 5, 6, 8};
    
    int missing = find_missing (A);
    std::cout << "First missing element = " << missing << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this is wrong

```
if(A.size()==1)  
return A.at(0)+1;
```

If `A` is `{2}` that code will return 3 when the correct answer is 1

Also

```
A.erase(remove_if(A.begin(), A.end(),[](const int i) {return i < 0; }),A.end());
```

should be

```
A.erase(remove_if(A.begin(), A.end(),[](const int i) {return i <= 0; }),A.end());
```

Also

```
return A.at(A.size()) + 1;
```

is a guaranteed vector out of bounds error.

Even a small amount of testing and debugging would have caught these errors. It's a habit you should get into.

I think there are far too many special cases in the code, which only serve to complicate the code and increase the chance of bugs.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is the implementation of the proposal given in the comment by PaulMcKenzie.

**So, all credits go to PaulMcKenzie**

It is not the fastest solution, but compact. The idea is basically.

- Sort the data
- Then compare the adjacent values, if the next value is equal to the previous value+1.

If not, then we found a gap. This can be implemented by using the function `std::adjacent_find`. Description can be found [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find).

We put all the side conditions into the lambda. If `std::adjacent_find` cannot find a value, then we take the next possible positive value.

I am not sure, what I could describe more. Please see the below example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int solution(std::vector<int>& data) {

    // Sort
    std::sort(data.begin(), data.end());

    // Check if there is a gap in the positive values
    const auto gap = std::adjacent_find(data.begin(), data.end(), [](const int p, const int n) { return (n !=p) && (n != (p + 1) && p>0); });

    // If there is no gap, the take the next positive value
    return (gap == data.end()) ?  (data.back() > 0 ? data.back() + 1 : 1) : *gap + 1;
}

int main() {
    //Some test cases
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> testCases{
        {1,3,6,4,1,2},
        {1,2,3},
        {-1,-3}
    };
    for (auto& testCase : testCases)
        std::cout << solution(testCase) << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

others have already pointed out what are the main errors, but I would like to invite you to try a different solution instead of trying to fix all the bugs and spend much time on debugging, because your solution seems a little overcomplicated.

Here I propose a way you can think about the problem:

- What is the minimum number the function can return? Since it returns a positive integer, it is 1, in the case 1 is not in the array. Since that we can use any number <=0 to see if we found our result scanning the vector (see next);
- In case one is not in the array, how do I find the wanted number? Your intuition is correct, if your vector is sorted it is easier: you can iterate over your data, and when you find an "hole" between two subsequent elements, then the value of the first element of the hole + 1 is you result
- What do I do if the array contains 1 and has no holes? Well, you return the smallest element that is not in the array, so the last element + 1. You may notice that by checking if your "candidate" value (that is a number that shouldn't be returned, so <=0) has changed during the scanning;

Let's go to the code:

```
int solution(std::vector<int>& v){
    int retVal=0;
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    for(int i=0; i<v.size()-1; i++){
        if(v[i]>0 && v[i+1]>v[i]+1){
            retVal=v[i]+1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(retVal==0) {
        if (v.back() > 0)
            retVal = v.back() + 1;
        else
            retVal = 1;
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

As suggested you can use the standard library a little bit more, but I think this is reasonably simple and efficient.

**Other note:**
I think your assignment does not bother you with this, but I mention just for completeness. Most of the times you don't want a function to modify your parameters: you can pass the vector "by value" meaning that actually you pass a complete copy of your data, without touching the original one, or you can pass a const reference and create a copy inside the function.

Comment: Sorry I misread the assignment and my previous solution was wrong. I edited the answer, so now it's ok @Roth-Tla-1